# Set current time in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, datetime, apache-flex

I am using DateField in my application.

```
<mx:DateField id="dtNewDate" selectedDate="{new Date()}" change="{dtChangeHandler(event)}" />
```

On change i am getting selected date. And time is 00:00. 
Now, i need current time instead of 00. So, i tried.

```
public function dtChangeHandler(event:CalendarLayoutChangeEvent):void
{
  var df:DateFormatter =new DateFormatter();
  df.formatString="MM/DD/YYYY HH:NN:QQ";
  trace(df.format(event.currentTarget.selectedDate))
}
```

It will give 24:00:00 instead of 00:00:00. Is there any way i can set current time?

I had also tried:

```
var date:Date = new Date();
selected_date = (event.currentTarget.selectedDate);
selected_date.setTime(date.getTime());
```

It will change time to current time. But, it will change date to today date.

Any help will greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the selected date and overwrite its time:

```
public function dtChangeHandler(event:CalendarLayoutChangeEvent):void
{
    var selectedDate:Date = event.currentTarget.selectedDate;
    var currentDate:Date = new Date();

    selectedDate.hours = currentDate.hours;
    selectedDate.minutes = currentDate.minutes;
    selectedDate.seconds = currentDate.seconds;

    trace(selectedDate);
}
```